# SQL statement case when day is weekend or weekday and join tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table  [Readings] which has a column [date]

And another table [Table_B] with a column [day_type] that is either 'WEEKEND' or 'WEEKDAY'  This table joins to another table [Table_C] which has two rows for each [Table_B] entry - one for each type of day for each.  Table_C has a column [rate] which I need the value for any given [date]

I'm actually building a complex query in Access.

I need to be able to get the day type out of the [date] in [Readings], convert it to a string and join it to [Table_B] then join this to [Table_C] to get the correct row.

something like "When date is a weekday, then [Table_B].[day_type] = "WEEKDAY" and then join the "WEEKDAY" to the third table to get the row for a weekday.
_

Hope this makes sense :O

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  I also fixed the database tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, yourdate) IN (7, 1) THEN 'WEEKEND' ELSE 'WEEKDAY' END)` with whatever your date field is to get what you need from Table_B and on.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Put put me in the right direction.  I was actually using a Postgresql database so the statement was a little bit different. 

table_b.day_type = CASE WHEN date_part('dow', readings.read_date) IN (0, 6) THEN 'WEEKEND' ELSE 'WEEKDAY' END)